# Extracting values from Initializationstring and returning as a key-value pair

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, initialization

I have part of an application initialization string below:

```
<Controls>
  <HtmlElement name="lnkLogIn" type="HtmlElement">
    <AttributeMatchPath matchtype="equals">
      <href>JavaScript:void(0)</href>
      <id>s_swepi_22</id>
    </AttributeMatchPath>
  </HtmlElement>
  <InputElement name="tbPassword" type="InputElement">
    <AttributeMatchPath matchtype="equals">
      <id>s_swepi_2</id>
    </AttributeMatchPath>
  </InputElement>
  <InputElement name="tbUserID" type="InputElement">
    <AttributeMatchPath matchtype="equals">
      <id>s_swepi_1</id>
    </AttributeMatchPath>
  </InputElement>
</Controls>
```

What i want to do in the code behind is a function that gets the Inputelement name and id for each control as key value pairs and returns a dictionary object or something similar from which we can extract the key value pair information.

This is basically being done to remove hardcoding of ID values....so a generic solution to get the elementname and id from the init string and store them as key value pairs would be really great....thanks in advance :)

PS: Using C#.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...Done.... :)

here's what i did: used system.xml.linq functionalities:

Here's the working code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main ( )
    {
        var xDoc = XElement.Load ( "ApplicationInit.xml" );
        var appSettingsDictionary = (xDoc.Descendants("InputElement")
            .Select ( item => new 
                             { 
                                 Key = item.Attribute("name").Value,
                                 Value = item.Descendants("id").First().Value 
                             }
                    )
                ).ToDictionary ( item => item.Key, item => item.Value );
    }
}
```

}